# How do I add css to a line like document.write(text[0]);

Tags: css, document.write

I've already tried this:

document.write(`<div class="line01">` + text[0] + `</div>`);

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to be a little more specific in terms of what you are trying to do. For instance, you can show the HTML output you are trying to get.

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS output. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That looks ok as far as the CSS goes, but the elements to output should be in a string:

Change this:

```
document.write(<div class="line01"> + text[0] + </div>);
```

To this:

```
document.write('<div class="line01">' + text[0] + '</div>');
```

More on `document.write` can be [found here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)